# check for dates syntax - teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to check for dates but after running the query below, it displays no result. Could someone recommend me the correct syntax?

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MY_DATABASE.AGREEMENT
WHERE end_dt=12/31/9999
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**12/31/9999** might look like a date for you but for the database it's a calculation:

**12 divided by 31 divided by 9999** and because this involves INTEGER division this results in an INTEGER **0**

So finally you compare a DATE to an INT and this results in typecasting the DATE to a INT.

The only reliable way to write a date literal in Teradata is **DATE** followed by a string with a **YYYY-MM-DD** format:

**DATE '9999-12-31'**

Similar for **TIME '12:34:56.1'** and **TIMESTAMP '2014-08-20 12:34:56.1'**

Comment: I wish more people would adhere to using the only reliable way to write a date literal in Teradata.

Comment: On the other hand, I wish Teradata wasn't quite so funky with dates.

Comment: @Andrew: What do you mean by "funky with dates"? What's simpler than a Standard SQL **DATE '2014-08-21'**? Without the DATE it's just a string and the conversion error prone. And it's much shorter than Oracle's **TO_DATE('2014-08-21', 'yyyy-mm-dd')**, seems like most Oracle developers never noticed, that they might use Standard syntax instead :-)

Comment: @dnoeth, the DATE bit is really only potentially needed because of how Teradata stores dates (as a signed int), yes?

Comment: @Andrew: **'2014-08-21'** without DATE is just a string and the conversion to a DATE might fail when the column has a different FORMAT. Teradata stores DATEs with a quite stupid calculation: (year - 1900) * 10000 + (month * 100) + day, i.e. 990811 = 1999-08-21, 1140821 = 2014-08-21, -9179 = 1899-08-21

Answer (score 1):

Is it a date column?  Then try `where end_dt = '9999-12-31'`.

Answer (score 0):

The question you ask is not very clear. The date you specify is language dependent.
Try 
    `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MY_DATABASE.AGREEMENT WHERE end_dt='99991231'`